# I want to make a Discord meme bot using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have recently made a [Python Discord bot](https://oneeyebot.blogspot.com/) and I want to built the same with JavaScript. I am totally new in this language and I don't know how I will add the meme command in.

in the Python version, I used a website heroukuapp to get memes from subreddit.

Here's how I made it in Python-

```
if message.content == 'Show me some memes':
            content = get("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme").text
            data = json.loads(content,)
            meme = discord.Embed(title=f"{data['title']}", Color = discord.Color.random()).set_image(url=f"{data['url']}")
            await message.channel.send("MEMEY.....MEMEY.....MEMEY......\n")
            await message.channel.send(embed=meme)
```

I want to use the same website for displaying memes in the JS bot (in embeds form). I have tried many APIs and seen many videos, but still I ccouldnt use them.

Till now, this is what I have done in JavaScript-

```
case "Show me some memes":
        message.channel.send("MEMEY.....MEMEY.....MEMEY......\n")
        
break;
```

Can anyone solve my query?

Thanks for viewing my post.

Comment: Please remove the python and discord.py tag as your question relates to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)  an Node.js based HTTPS request library to request the API and further parse the response and use the things you need from the body ( alternatives - node-fetch ( previously snekfetch - ESM module ))

Here's an example:

```js
const got = require("got");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
got("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme").then( (response) => {
const data = JSON.parse(response.body);
let meme = new MessageEmbed
.setTitle(`${data['title']}`);
.setColor("RANDOM");
.setImage(`${data['url']}`)
message.channel.send({ content: "MEMEY..MEMEY...MEMEY...", embeds: [meme]});
});
```

This is specifically for discord.js v13 if you're on any version that's below 13 you may directly pass the embed object like so:

```js
message.channel.send(meme);
```

Comment: Also appearently the API you're using is practically weird and doesn't return a valid JSON response since I'm unable to parse it I recommend you to use the official Reddit API instead [you can find it here](https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/random/.json)

Comment: No issues! If it helped you make sure to accept it with the ✓ button and upvote it with the  button. Welcome to stackoverflow 